# WinSock Send Multiple Request & Shutdown Issue

Tags: c++, winsock2

I need to send multiple request (command) to server at port 55005.
My first request get process successfully & I received out put also.
But for second request it gives error (WSAESHUTDOWN - Error 10058). 
After first request I call 
    shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
Then only server process the first request & send me output.
Now can re-open socket processing next request ?**

How I can process multiple request after shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND) ?
Thanks in Advance for your suggestions.

**I send the first request , wait for first reply. After first request reply, I can send next request. This is business logic requirement. I don't want to open a new connection for each request.**

Snapshot Code start here ---------------->

```
**//This for loop will send multiple request to Servers.**
for(it = CommandList.begin(); it != CommandList.end() ; it++ )
{
    //get each command request & send it to server.
    std::string  sendBuf; // =  (*it);
     sendBuf= *it;
    int length = (int)strlen(sendBuf.c_str());
    //----------------------
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, (char*)sendBuf.c_str(), length, 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);


    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            wprintf(L"Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            wprintf(L"Connection closed\n");
        else
            wprintf(L"recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );
}
```

Comment: Why would you shutdown the socket for sending when you have more data to send? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: And why do you use `strlen` to get the length of a `std::string`?

Comment: I send the first request , wait for first reply. After first request reply, I can send next request. This is business logic requirement. I don't want to open a new connection for each request.

Comment: And so what? You still have more requests to send, so don't shutdown. It's as simple as that. You should not do it _unless you have absolutely no more to send_. You can still receive data, all sockets are fully duplex, i.e. can send and receive at the same time.

Comment: I don't want to open a new connection for each request.

Comment: shutdown tell to server first request is received & process it. So server can reply to my first request. Till this it look good. But After Shutdown How I can send my next request ?

Comment: Once you shutdown you have to open again. You should think about modifying the protocol to include some kind of end-of-request marker, or to include the length of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joachim said, don't call `shutdown` until you are done with the connection.  This TCP socket is a "stream"... stuff can go back and forth at will.  You as a programmer have to determine where "requests" and "responses" begin and end... don't use `shutdown` for that.

Comment: since you seem to be sending zero-terminated strings, use a zero as your request/response delimiter.  instead of sending `length`, send `sendBuf.length() + 1`.  delete the shutdown code (or move it to after the loop).  in your receive loop, keep appending to a std::string until you receive a 0 in the data.